# My service is started immediately in my alarmmanager

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

This Method is in MyClass.java that extends Service

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    settPeriodicService = this;
    HOUR = 0;
    MINUTE = 0;
    message="Happy birthday!";
    if(running) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,HOUR);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,MINUTE);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,1);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
        running = true;
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Why does MyService start immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,HOUR);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,MINUTE);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,1);
```

Above calendar represents a time in the past because you set the day to january 1st with `calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,1);`. Setting a time in the past will trigger the alarm immediately.

You probably want to do this:

```
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,1);
```

to set the calendar to tomorrow.

Comment: if i sett the HOUR and MINUTE to like a later time, would it go off?

Comment: Yes it would go off

Comment: Would it og off on my computers time or my Android Emulator time?, i cant manage to get it to go off in the emulator time..

Comment: I don't know, I never use the emulator